# Bulk insert - create some columns' values based on another column's known values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am creating a database of country and year specific data. I have a table of countries that includes each country's name, UN code (numeric), 2-digit alpha code, 3-digit alpha code, and ISO code.

There will be many other tables in this database whose rows each include country codes, a year, and a data point of interest. For instance, a "total population" table's rows would each include a year, a population figure, and the UN, alpha-2, alpha-3, and ISO codes for the country to which the record corresponds. So, for any given country, there would be many records (one per year).

The challenge: I'm getting data from several sources, and different sources use different coding systems. I am using CSV files to import all of the data. For instance, here's the query that loads the data for the Countries table.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data/countryCodes.csv'
INTO TABLE Countries
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(country_name, alpha2_code, alpha3_code, un_code, iso_code);
```

Of course, any given UN code only corresponds to one 2-digit alpha code, one 3-digit alpha code, and one ISO code. I want to be able to import a CSV that only includes one of these codes, and have the database automatically populate the other codes' entries for each row. For instance, if I imported population data coded by UN code, the database would automatically reference the corresponding other codes in the Countries table and insert the appropriate values.

Is there a way to do this with SQL? If I create this functionality in the database, it will be far easier to systematize the server- and client-side associations between different types of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honnestly I am having a hard time figuring out what your issue is / what you are really wanting to do...

To be usable on the database level, your final dataset should look like this:

Table Country Code

```
+----+----+-----+----+----+
| id | un | iso | a2 | a3 |
+----+----+-----+----+----+
| 1  | FR | FR  | FR | FR |
| 2  | .. | ..  | .. | .. |
+----+----+-----+----+----+
```

Table Population

```
+----+------+-----------+----------+
| id | year | idCountry | value    |
+----+------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | 1979 | 1         | 50000000 |
| 2  | 1980 | 1         | 50000000 |
+----+------+-----------+----------+
```

To convert "direct" value from CSV to the index value something like this could be done:

```
ALTER TABLE population ADD extCC CHAR(2);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data/population.csv'
INTO TABLE population (year,value,extCC)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS (extCC, year, value);

UPDATE population, countryCode SET population.idCountry=countryCode.id WHERE countryCode.iso = population.extCC;

ALTER TABLE population DROP extCC;
```

Comment: Thanks...was definitely making this harder than it needed to be by not just referencing the table id of the country, rather than one of the country codes.

Comment: Circling back after implementing - this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: With pleasure, don't forgot to upvote and accept answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Decide on which `country_code` to use for `country_code` everywhere.  (You will keep the table you described that shows the mapping between ISO, UN, etc.)
2. `LOAD DATA ...` - but not directly into the real table.  Instead into table `t`.
3. Add a column to `t`, then lookup each code in the ISO/UN/etc table and put the `country_code` value in.
4. Then copy the rows from `t` to the real table.  Note the 'real' table will have only the preferred `country_code`.

The general principle here is to cleanse and cannonify disparate data as part of the loading process.  Sure, it takes an extra step, but it is worth it.  Keep your 'real' table clean.

What will you do about Czechoslovakia --> Czech Republic + Slovakia?  And Yugoslavia.  And Upper Volta --> Burkina Faso?  Etc.